# Multilingual Apps with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, translation

is there a standardized way to create jQuery Mobile Apps (with Phonegap) in multiple languages?

Comment: Does PhoneGap use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com)? At any rate, it looks like PhoneGap itself does not yet have i18n support but [it's on the 1.x roadmap](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/28291160/roadmap-planning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same question... I found the microsoft solution from "lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com" not very helpful. But thanks anyways ;-)

I wrote my own localization function with javascript and json.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx) is the link that you can use for using multiple languages in your app. I don't have a working example right now but I think it will work fine in case of jQuery mobile without problem.

Answer (score -1):

in my case my webapp is developed with jquerymobile and php, so i have 1 php file for every lang i want to support.

example:

if the user has configured his language as english i include on my header the English.php if the user uses spanish i include the spanish.php:

english.php:

```
<?php
$sentence="this is a sentence";
?>
```

spanish.php

```
<?php
$sentence="esto es una frase";
?>
```

if you "echo $sentence" it will take the one from the file you included. I store the selected language in a cookie and include the proper language file.

Comment: Mobile App not the same as Web Mobile App. So, this answer is not valid for the needs of the asker. Also, I think is better option to use __( string );

Comment: This is not a good solution for a mobile app as, to my knowledge, the handset does not parse PHP. You could use jQuery.post to fire off a request to a web server for the language file and then re-populate the page content with the response. Thus, your app will always need network connection.